# Back button not working after reloading DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink

I am currently using this code for a website, when you click a link the central Div is refreshed, thus saving some bandwidth. The code works like a charm, the only problem is that when I click the back button it takes me out of the page, as the browser is only registering one visit to the site. Any workaround for this?
JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxdestination="";

function getdata(what,where) { 
 try {
   xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():
        new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 catch (e) {
 }

 document.getElementById(where).innerHTML ="<center><br><br><img id='loader'      src='carga.png'></center>";
 ajaxdestination=where;
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = triggered;
 xmlhttp.open("GET", what);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 return false;
}

function triggered() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    document.getElementById(ajaxdestination).innerHTML =xmlhttp.responseText;
}
</script>
```

And my links look like this:

`<a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getdata('pag/identidad.php', 'container');">`

EDIT:
I am talking about the browser's back button :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you additionally change your links to `<a class="active" href="pag/identidad.php" onclick="getdata(this.href, 'container'); return false">` or better: `<a class="active" href="pag/identidad.php" onclick="return getdata(this.href, 'container')">` and put the return false in the getdata function

Comment: When I add your code I only get redirected to the DIV. What I am trying is to have that div opened replacing the current div's content. Did I do something wrong? I added the reutrn false; right before catch(e){}

Answer (score 2):

where is your back button .. it is in your website or it is browser back button .what you want to do when you click back button , when you click  back button in browser it  will leave you from the current page to last visited page .

Comment: It's always good to request more info if a question is perceived as being unclear or lacking context. In this instance, I do however think that your feedback would be better suited and of greater value in the form of a comment. ;]

Comment: i tried to comment, i cant able to do it as i had lower reputation score

Comment: The browser's back button

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery address plugin
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/